# how to get windows login name in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a web-app with C# where I want to get the user's logged in computer name.
This page will be called by another web address.

I've tried several ways, but not getting the results as I want it. 
Here's my code :

```
1. txtBookBy.Text = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
2. txtBookBy.Text = User.Identity.Name;
3. txtBookBy.Text = Request.ServerVariables[5];
4. txtBookBy.Text = System.Environment.UserName;
5. txtBookBy.Text = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
6. txtBookBy.Text = Request.QueryString["user"];
```

This's the result, when i called by another web address.

```
1. txtBookBy.Text = "compName\ASPNET";
2. txtBookBy.Text = "";
3. txtBookBy.Text = "";
4. txtBookBy.Text = "ASPNET";
5. txtBookBy.Text = "";
6. txtBookBy.Text = @Variable;
```

This's the result, when i run with visual studio.

```
1. txtBookBy.Text = "PT\asromi";
2. txtBookBy.Text = "PT\asromi";
3. txtBookBy.Text = "PT\asromi";
4. txtBookBy.Text = "asromi";
5. txtBookBy.Text = "PT\asromi";
6. txtBookBy.Text = @Variable;
```

the results I want :
When i called by another web address, the result like "asromi"

some people told me to reconfigure IIS.

1. activate Windows Integrated Authentication
2. turn off anonymous users either

but, i really newbie with IIS.
please explain techniques detail, what i have to do.

Comment: have you tried `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`? it's recommended here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36e1bcfa-a46a-47a8-8b21-78357efe866b/how-to-get-windows-login-credentials-using-cnet

Comment: yes i did, but i get this error : CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Security.Principal.IIdentity' to 'string'

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user's [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object under Windows Authentication by:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

and then you can get the information about the user like identity.Name.

Please note you need to have HttpContext for these code and `WindowsAuthentication` should be enabled in `Web.config` file

```
<security>
    <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
    </authentication>
</security>
```

Comment: before edit [web.config] the result is [compName\IUSR_compName]. but i don't understand how to change the [web.config]. this is my [web.config]             <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows" />

Comment: when i paste the web.config like your ask. i get this error  "Unrecognized element 'anonymousAuthentication'." please explain to me

Comment: oh so u r worry about the hierarchy of web config??  check the http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code

```
public class DNSHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the username.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The request.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetUsername(System.Web.HttpRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioex)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null)
            {
                return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var username = DNSHelper.GetUsername(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request);
```

Comment: the result is [compName\IUSR_compName]